# How to get the accumulated sum of the children in an Hierarchical tree?

Tags: sql, oracle

Table "salary"'s columns are att_month, emp_id(points to employee's emp_id), total.
Table "organization" columns are ID, IDParent, name.
Table "employee"'s column are emp_id, emp_name, dep_id (points to organization's ID).

The target is to calculate summary of every department, each month, according to these three tables. I wonder if someone can provide the SQL query or optimize mine?

My current query is as follows:

```
   select * from (select yy.IDParent, xx.ID, name, sum(heji) total
       from (select CONNECT_BY_ROOT(ID) ID, heji
                  from (select aa.ID,
                           aa.IDParent,
                           aa.name,
                           nvl(sum(HJ), 0) as heji
                          from (select * from organization) aa,
                           (select att_month,
                                   b.dep_id,
                                   sum(total) as HJ
                              from salary a, employee b
                             where b.emp_id = a.emp_id
                               and to_char(att_month, 'yyyy-mm') =
                                   '2012-05'
                             group by att_month, b.dep_id) bb
                     where aa.ID = bb.dep_id(+)
                     group by aa.ID, aa.IDParent, aa.name)
                connect by prior ID = IDParent) xx,
               organization yy
         where xx.ID = yy.ID
         group by yy.IDParent, xx.ID, name)
    connect by prior ID = IDParent
     start with ID = '000';
```

But, it's too long and need be optimized. How?

```
    CREATE TABLE "EMPLOYEE" 
       (    "ID" NUMBER(5,0), 
        "EMP_ID" VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "PASSWORD" VARCHAR2(8) DEFAULT 1, 
        "EMP_NAME" VARCHAR2(30), 
        "DEP_ID" VARCHAR2(5), 
        "LEV" CHAR(1), 
        "SEX" CHAR(1), 
        "CATEGORY" VARCHAR2(20), 
        "EDU" VARCHAR2(8), 
        "BIRTHDAY" DATE, 
        "GN" DATE, 
        "RJ" DATE, 
        "PID" VARCHAR2(18), 
        "LTY" CHAR(1), 
        "GWMC" VARCHAR2(40), 
        "ZJ" VARCHAR2(20), 
        "JSZW" VARCHAR2(20), 
        "JSJB" VARCHAR2(20), 
        "GWGZ" NUMBER(6,2), 
        "MEMO" VARCHAR2(40), 
        "MODILEV" NUMBER(*,0) DEFAULT 0, 
        "STATION" NUMBER(5,0), 
         CONSTRAINT "PK_EMPLOYEE" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
      USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
      STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
      PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
      TABLESPACE "JXKP_INDEX"  ENABLE, 
         CONSTRAINT "UK_EMPLOYEE" UNIQUE ("EMP_ID")
      USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
      STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
      PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
      TABLESPACE "JXKP_INDEX"  ENABLE
       ) PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
      STORAGE(INITIAL 196608 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
      PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
      TABLESPACE "JXKP" ;

      CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "PK_EMPLOYEE" ON "EMPLOYEE" ("ID") 
      PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
      STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
      PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
      TABLESPACE "JXKP_INDEX" ;

      CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "UK_EMPLOYEE" ON "EMPLOYEE" ("EMP_ID") 
      PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
      STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
      PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
      TABLESPACE "JXKP_INDEX" ;

      ALTER TABLE "EMPLOYEE" ADD CONSTRAINT "PK_EMPLOYEE" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
      USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
      STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
      PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
      TABLESPACE "JXKP_INDEX"  ENABLE;

      ALTER TABLE "EMPLOYEE" MODIFY ("EMP_ID" NOT NULL ENABLE);

      ALTER TABLE "EMPLOYEE" ADD CONSTRAINT "UK_EMPLOYEE" UNIQUE ("EMP_ID")
      USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
      STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
      PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
      TABLESPACE "JXKP_INDEX"  ENABLE;


      CREATE TABLE "SALARY" 
       (    "EMP_ID" VARCHAR2(5), 
        "ATT_MONTH" DATE, 
        "JXGZ" NUMBER(8,2), 
        "YCXJJ" NUMBER(8,2), 
        "BZZJT" NUMBER(8,2), 
        "YBJT" NUMBER(8,2), 
        "WQJT" NUMBER(8,2), 
        "JBGZ" NUMBER(8,2), 
        "QTJ" NUMBER(8,2), 
        "BF" NUMBER(8,2), 
        "GSKH" NUMBER(8,2), 
        "BMKH" NUMBER(8,2), 
        "TOTAL" NUMBER(8,2), 
        "MEMO" VARCHAR2(80), 
        "CHECKLOCK" VARCHAR2(1) DEFAULT '2', 
        "MODILOCK" NUMBER(*,0) DEFAULT 1, 
        "MODITIME" DATE, 
        "SGSFF" VARCHAR2(1) DEFAULT 0, 
        "CT" NUMBER(8,2), 
        "RCJB" NUMBER(8,2), 
        "XJFF" NUMBER(8,2), 
        "STATION" NUMBER(11,0), 
        "DEP_ID" VARCHAR2(5), 
        "ID" NUMBER(11,0), 
         CONSTRAINT "PK_SALARY" PRIMARY KEY ("EMP_ID", "ATT_MONTH")
      USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
      STORAGE(INITIAL 196608 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
      PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
      TABLESPACE "JXKP_INDEX"  ENABLE
       ) PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
      STORAGE(INITIAL 327680 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
      PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
      TABLESPACE "JXKP" ;

      CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "PK_SALARY" ON "SALARY" ("EMP_ID", "ATT_MONTH") 
      PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
      STORAGE(INITIAL 196608 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
      PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
      TABLESPACE "JXKP_INDEX" ;

      ALTER TABLE "SALARY" ADD CONSTRAINT "PK_SALARY" PRIMARY KEY ("EMP_ID", "ATT_MONTH")
      USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
      STORAGE(INITIAL 196608 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
      PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
      TABLESPACE "JXKP_INDEX"  ENABLE;


      CREATE TABLE "organization" 
       (    "IDParent" VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "ID" VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "ZJMC" VARCHAR2(60), 
        "ZJJS" VARCHAR2(50), 
         CONSTRAINT "PK_organization" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
      USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
      STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
      PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
      TABLESPACE "JXKP_INDEX"  ENABLE
       ) PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
      STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
      PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
      TABLESPACE "JXKP" ;

      CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "PK_organization" ON "organization" ("ID") 
      PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
      STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
      PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
      TABLESPACE "JXKP_INDEX" ;

      ALTER TABLE "organization" ADD CONSTRAINT "PK_organization" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
      USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
      STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
      PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
      TABLESPACE "JXKP_INDEX"  ENABLE;

      ALTER TABLE "organization" MODIFY ("IDParent" NOT NULL ENABLE);

      ALTER TABLE "organization" MODIFY ("ID" NOT NULL ENABLE);
```

Comment: You're clearly using Oracle because of the `(+)` outer join notation.  However, your first step should be to rewrite the query using regular join notations, both inner and outer as appropriate.  The two levels of CONNECT BY PRIOR don't make it easy to understand what's going on, either.  Frankly, it is too convoluted looking for me to even want to start thinking about understanding what it is doing (and I've got a reasonably high pain threshold for SQL problems).

Comment: Please provide create table statements, a few example rows and expected output.

Comment: please, conceptually, what is "organization"? And what is a parent of an organization? Is it the idea of a "holding"?

Comment: This is an off topic sidebar, not an answer to your question.  If the data were organized using nested sets instead of adjacency lists, the query would be ridiculously simple.  I realize that you have to work with what you are given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to simplify your query, have a look at this please:

```
SELECT 
    yy.IDParent, 
    xx.ROOT_ID, 
    yy.name, 
    SUM(xx.heji) total
FROM (
    SELECT 
        CONNECT_BY_ROOT(t.ID) ROOT_ID,
        t.heji
    FROM    (
                SELECT 
                    dept.ID,
                    dept.IDParent,
                    dept.name,
                    NVL(bb.HJ, 0) as heji
                FROM organization dept LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         (SELECT 
                                att_month,
                                b.dep_id,
                                SUM(total) as HJ
                          FROM 
                                salary a INNER JOIN employee b ON b.emp_id = a.emp_id
                          WHERE 
                                TO_CHAR(att_month, 'yyyy-mm') = '2012-05'
                          GROUP BY 
                                att_month, 
                                b.dep_id
                         ) bb ON dept.ID = bb.dep_id
            ) t
     CONNECT BY PRIOR t.ID = t.IDParent
    ) xx INNER JOIN organization yy ON xx.ROOT_ID = yy.ID
GROUP BY 
    yy.IDParent, 
    xx.ROOT_ID, 
    yy.name;
```

Comment: What did you simplify? And what will your new query accomplish? Did you test it?

Comment: Hi, I found out some unnecessary operations. But unfortunately i don't have your model nor datas to try it out. I still think it will give you a hand regarding to the performances. However, I assumed that what you needed was the accumulated total salary for may 2012 of all the parent organizations and their children.

Comment: Your result is the same as mine.I've tested it.Thought I've express it clearly, your assumption is exactly what i thought.Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your result is the same as mine, and yours is about 4 times faster than mine.PERFECT.I've tested it.Thought I've express it clearly, your assumption is exactly what i thought.Thanks a lot!

Comment: great! And I'm sure we could go deeper having a look at your table structure in details :) If it is a critical query in your job I'll be glad to go further with you.. for fun :-)

Comment: I've posted my table strcture in details. it took me some time to find the best post place :)  Thanks for you trying to figure out more faults.

Answer (score 0):

- Add an index on organization: (IDParent), with COMPUTE STATISTICS
- Add a function based index on salary: TO_CHAR(att_month, 'yyyy-mm')

As well, since you are widely parsing a bunch of tables, don't forget to check from when your global statistics have been generated. If you decide you generate them again, this is not necessary to use COMPUTE STATISTICS when creating the keys.

rgds.

Comment: I edited this answer after better checking your stucture! It should be good now :-)